# how to push the user after login or register to the home page in react js?

Tags: reactjs

all my handlesubmit work correctly except the push function  ,she worked in other places

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const form = this.props.form;
      const { user } = this.state;
      this.setState({ submitted: true });
      let data = new FormData(); // creates a new FormData object

      data.append('password', form.getFieldValue('user.password'));
      data.append('nom', form.getFieldValue('user.nom'));
      data.append('prenom',form.getFieldValue('user.prenom'));
      data.append('email', form.getFieldValue('user.email'));
      data.append('residence',form.getFieldValue('user.residence'));
      data.append('phone',form.getFieldValue('user.phone'));
      data.append('username',form.getFieldValue('user.username') );

      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/register/', data)
      .then(res => { 
        console.log(res)  
        return res // data comes from the return of res
     }) 
    .then(data => { if(data.status === 201){
      history.push('/home');
  console.log(data.username)}})
      .catch(err=>console.log(err))

 };
```

no errors was shown

Answer (score 0):

did you setup correctly react-router with the HOC ?

Example :

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const Button = ({ history }) => (
  <button
    type='button'
    onClick={() => { history.push('/new-location') }}
  >
    Click Me!
  </button>
)

export default withRouter(Button)
```

In your case use `this.props.history`